# Settings that don't get deleted when the app is uninstalled

Tags: android

I know that both preferences and [files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834338/storing-files-on-android-that-dont-get-deleted-on-update-or-uninstall) get deleted when the app is uninstalled.

Is there *any* type of persistent storage that **doesn't** get deleted upon app uninstall?

If I want to save some data in between uninstalls and re-installs, is my only recourse to send it over the Internet to some server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store data on a folder on the sdcard, or use the Data Backup API (which, in a sense, is to send it over the net to some server, but at least transparently)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

Comment: Since I only want to avoid charging a user twice for an app already paid for (if not purchased via the Android Market as it doesn't allow in-app payments using PayPal), your Data Backup API suggestion is excellent. I would refrain from abusing external storag, as @hackbod suggested. Accepted.

Comment: @ef2011 yes, it sounds like the ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported way.  When a user uninstalls the app, everything about it should be removed.

You can abuse external storage to try to get around that, but be aware that we are increasingly providing tools for users to find out about applications littering external storage with stuff like that and tools to clean it up.

Comment: Thanks + 1. The idea is to avoid charging a user twice for an app already paid for -- **if not** purchased via the Android Market. For example, if the user pays via PayPal for an upgrade from a free version to a paid version.